# I am unable to open port 8080 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: server

I am installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my machine, I am using Cyberpanal on it. Along with that, I have installed the Ookla server on a different subdomain. For example- Cyberpanel is running on port 8090 of **abcd.com** & I have installed Ookla on **speedtest.wxyz.com**. Ookla server required port 8080 for this.

I am unable to open port 8080 on it. I tried checking which service is using port 8080 but it's not in the list, meaning no other service is using it.

Can anyone please help?

----------------------------------Edit in Question ------------------

Now port 8080 is in use by the Ookla server but a ping from the local server is absolute ZERO with 100% packet loss. Subdomain *speedtest.wxyz.com* is listing to port 443. `sudo lsof -i :8080` shows that port 8080 is being used by OoklaServer.

Comment: Is ookla running? what is the output of sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 8080 ? does the ookla process output any log information that you might use to debug this issue?

Comment: Use `sudo lsof -i :8080` to see if any process has the port open. Read `man lsof`.

Comment: ```COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
OoklaServ 11710 root    6u  IPv4  98222      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
OoklaServ 11710 root   10u  IPv4  97193      0t0  UDP *:8080
```

This is the output of ```sudo lsof -t :8080``` OoklaServer is using this port, but when I am trying to access it from IP or subdomain it's inaccessible.